# Magento running under MSSQL

Tags: magento-1, database

Has anyone managed to get Magento running under MSSQL?
Since 1.6 there is the possiblity to change the PDO driver, using some steps:

1. Rename Mysql.php files to Mssql.php

   app/code/core/mage/Core/Model/Resource/Type/Db/Pdo/Mysql.php

   lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

   lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php
2. Modify the files to actually use Mssql
3. Modify app/etc/local.xml and app/etc/config.xml to use mssql adapter

This basically works, but then you are running into the problem that all (or at least most) install scripts are using MySQL specific syntax.
Has anyone undergone the hassle of porting them all to MSSQL?

Any other thoughts in this regard besides waiting for Magento 2.0 to support this natively?! ;)

Comment: you need to change all the mysql resource model. The Problem is, all the classes use MySQL syntax (!= SQL syntax). MySQL is not always SQL standard complaint.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I would hope that there are only a few you will have to rewrite, since resource models generally use the abstracted notation like $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()->from($this->getTable('catalog/category'))->where('path = ?', (string)$rootId); etc, so these should still work under MSSQL

Comment: As I said, you have to reimplement the MYSQL resource models. All other should be abstracted :)

Comment: Did you find an answer? Share it! :-)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt No, I did not find anything, yet. It seems this is too much work and we will have to wait for Magento 2

Answer (score 1):

There was a presentation from Maksym Iaroshenko at [Developers Paradise – Friends, Fun, Snow](http://www.developers-paradise.com/): [Magento non-MySQL implementations](http://ice.eltrino.com/eltrino-paradise-2013-maksym_iaroshenko.pdf)

I also found this video (same guy) presenting at Meet Magento Poland: 
["Magento non-MySQL implementations" Maksym Iaroshenko, Dmytro Vasylenko, Eltrino](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvl-pwlIBjw)

During one of the Magento Hackathons this repo was created: [MongoDB-OrderTransactions](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MongoDB-OrderTransactions)

I don't see a working version of Magento 2 on anything else than MySQL in the next 12 months (at least).

The challange with another RDBMS and Magento is that just porting the database tables with the same schema won't be a solution, because some refactoring is needed, some stuff should be moved at a database level (depends on RDBMS, would be nice to see stored views used).

Another challange is providing a set of tools for the actual migration and management of the environment so developers that would want to contribute not to break their heads for couple of weeks just to get some kind of functional dev environment.

Start a repo on github and see how other people feel about this.